# sql query update only one field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm building a PHP and sql API and I'm trying to create the update query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE boxes 
    SET box_id = :box_id, channel = :channel, status = :status 
    WHERE id = $id";
```

The problem is that if I just update the channel, for example, the other fields became empty in my database.

I want the user to be able to choose if he wants to update all fields, just some or only one.

Thanks

Comment: You must past your whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `coalesce()`?

```
UPDATE boxes
    SET box_id = COALESCE(:box_id, box_id),
        channel = COALESCE(:channel, channel),
        status = COALESCE(:status, status)
    WHERE id = :id;
```

Notice that I made `:id` a named parameter as well.

Comment: Thanks, thats it!! :)

Comment: Can I ask you why did you made :id parameter as well? - @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @ribeiro.csa - The question is more why you didn't. Use parameters for all input data or you will still be open for sql injections.